# z-index values don't stack correctly

Tags: html, css, z-index

To my naive understanding, z-index values enable the correct stacking order using CSS. As such, I want the circular call button to have a greater z-index than the z-index of the map, which should have a greater z-index than the bottom red boxes (`.subThreeAndFour`). Thus, I assigned them z-indices of 0,-1, and -2, respectively. However, as shown, the map is still below `.subThreeAndFour` (the two red boxes on the bottom):

[image: de]

Regarding the following code:

```
iframe{
    position: absolute;
    left:0.6%;
    top:49.3%;
    width:91.3%;
    height: 48%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.subThreeAndFour, .subThree, .subFour{
    z-index: -2;
}

.mainCircleCall{
    background-image: url(https://www.falconemergency.com/wp-content/themes/falcon/images/call3.gif);
    background-size: 120% 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px greenyellow solid;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Full code at https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/XGVNKY?editors=0110

Comment: Your pen is modified with someone else's changes it shows map over it

Comment: Nope; those are my changes. I changed the z-index values, so that the map *is* stacked on top of `.subThreeAndFour`, but still on top of `.mainCircleCall`. I still don't know how to fix it; Is it because one of my elements isn't positioned?

Comment: Does your `.subThreeAndFour, .subThree, .subFour` has non-static position? `z-index` must have also position applied to take effect.

Comment: @Justinas Yep, I realized that, and Guatam fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what u want 
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/gautamnaik1994/pen/gEvwoZ?editors=1100)

So basically I moved the order of some html tags inside .sub-container

```
    <div class="subThreeAndFour">
        <div class="subThree"></div> //moved up
        <div class="subFour"></div> //moved up
        <div class="mapWrapper">
            <iframe id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=brooklyn%20tech&t=k&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>

    </div>
    <div class="mainCircle">h</div> //moved down
```

So basically, the elements which is last, is drawn last (i.e. on top of other in your case)

In your case putting `maincircle` last, I tell the browser, to draw it last.This will position it on top of the stacking order.

Comment: Exactly! Yes! Thanks so much.